# WPF ListCollectionView CustomSort - turn off sorting

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, datagrid

I have implemented custom sort for a `ListCollection` view. The data is displayed in a `DataGrid`. The actual sorting is functioning. I have this code:

```
    private ICollectionView CV { get; set; }

    public void Sort()
    {
        if (CV is ListCollectionView view)
        {
            view.CustomSort = new ConnectionViewModelComparer();
        }
    }


    public void StopSorting()
    {

        if (CV is ListCollectionView view)
        {
            view.IsLiveSorting = false;
            //view.CustomSort = null;
        }
    }
```

I want to be able to turn on/off real time sorting when data is edited or added. I thought that setting the `ListConnectionView` property `IsLiveSorting` to false would achieve this but if I edit data in the `DataGrid` the rows are still sorted in real time. Have I misunderstood something?

I thought that I could solve this issue by setting `view.CustomSort` to `null` but by doing so the data is returned to the original state/order before sorting. Is there a simple way to turn off sorting and keeping the data in the same order as it was before sorting is turned off?

Comment: I don't know if this is your problem, but it would be better to cast to `ICollectionViewLiveShaping` instead of `ListCollectionView`.

Comment: I decided that I don't need the live sorting feature at all in the application. But still I wasn't able to disable it when using the `ListCollectionView`. Not to get stuck with this issue I made a temporary solution where I use a `List` and sort that. Not an efficient solution but i will do for now.

Comment: @MikeStrobel `ListCollectionView` implements `ICollectionViewLiveShaping` and has an inherited property of `IsLiveSorting`. The `ListCollectionView` also allows us to include custom sort objects that implement the `IComparer` interface.